# Form loses all styles?

Tags: css, ajax, forms, internet-explorer-8

I have a form that is generated via ajax (facebox).

In FF, Chrome, IE > 8 it all works fine, however in IE < 9 the form has no styles.
[image: Image Diff]

What would be causing this*?

*some effects are missing due to CSS3, but css3 is not height/width/padding.

---

Using IE's "element source with style" on the *group name* input gives:

**IE8**

```
<html>
<head><style>
BODY
{
    color: #4f5155;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-image: url("../images/pageBackground.png");
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: top;
    background-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
}
#facebox
{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
#facebox .popup
{
    position: relative;
}
#facebox .content
{
    width: 370px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: table;
    background-image: none;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

</style></head>
<body><div id="facebox" style="left: 477px; top: 40px;"><div class="popup"><div class="content"><div class="inputSeperator">

<input name="name" type="text" />

</div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

**IE9**

```
<html>
<head><style>
body
{
    color: #4f5155;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-image: url("../images/pageBackground.png");
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: top;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
}
form#newForm
{
    width: 500px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-top-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-right-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-left-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 18px rgba(200,200,200,1);
    background-image: none;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
form#newForm input[type='text'], form#newForm input[type='password'], form#newForm textarea, form#newForm select
{
    width: 97%;
    color: #555;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-top-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-right-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-left-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    background-image: none;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
}
#facebox
{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
#facebox .popup
{
    border-top-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-right-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
#facebox .content
{
    width: 370px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: table;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    background-image: none;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

</style></head>
<body><div id="facebox" style="left: 397.5px; top: 40.5px;"><div class="popup"><div class="content"><form id="newForm" action="none" method="POST"><div class="inputSeperator">

<input name="name" type="text" />

</div></form></div></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Screenshots are nice, but you should really post the relevant code.

Comment: +1 don't understand why this was downvoted.

Comment: @Pekka, unfortunately I cannot post a live link due to the page being inaccessible outside of our office.

Comment: Can you post a demo that reproduces your problem, perhaps on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Hmmmm, Anyone notice what I just noticed, Its not the styles not being applied, the form tag is actually disappearing on IE <9...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what it was,

malformed html,

If you have a look at the html there is an extra ending div.

for some reason this was causing ie8 to simply discard the actual form elements, absolutely strange behavior...